# Hibernate annotation for mysql datatype SET

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a `MySQL` table where the `dataType` for the attribute `workingDays` is SET. something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `course` (
`courseId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`courseName` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`courseDescription` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`courseDuration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`courseBatchSize` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`courseEnrolmentDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
`workingDays` set('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday') DEFAULT NULL,
`courseFee` float DEFAULT NULL,
`isScholarshipAvailable` enum('Y','N') DEFAULT NULL,
`scholarshipCriteria` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`scholarshipExamDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
`successRate` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`rating` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`otherInfo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`courseDiscount` float DEFAULT NULL,
`institute` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`exam` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`courseId`),
KEY `FK_INS` (`institute`),
KEY `FK_EX` (`exam`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_EX` FOREIGN KEY (`exam`) REFERENCES `exam` (`examId`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_INS` FOREIGN KEY (`institute`) REFERENCES `institute` (`instituteId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='contains course info';
```

Now correspondingly I want to map with the `pojo` using `jpa` annotations. Presently I am doing it like this

```
@Column(name = "workingDays", nullable = false, unique = false)
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.settype")
private Set<String> workingDays;
```

where the annotation @Column is from package javax.persistence. With @Type annotation which is from hibernate package I am getting an error

```
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.type.settype
```

My pom.xml file has the following dependencies added

```
    <!-- MySQL database driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.30</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate library dependecy start -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate library dependecy end -->
```

I am not sure how to resolve this issue. any insight or other workaround for mapping to a set in `MySQL` database will be helpful.

EDIT: Also suggest if I can store the working days attribute in database without using SET. This working day attribute is for a particular Company class and I need to show what are the working days of that company to end user. Suggestion regarding the datatype will be really helpful too.

Thanks.

Comment: It is org.hibernate.type.SetType not org.hibernate.type.settype

Comment: Thanks.
However, Now I am getting this error

      Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate Type: org.hibernate.type.SetType


Could you provide an example how to use this annotation? I am fairly new to hibernate

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.setType")` declaration on simple types. You may remove it from the field declaration.

@Type annotation is required only when you are working with advanced custom types

```
class Account {

  @Type(type="com.something.type.CustomDateType")
  @Column(name = "OPEN_DATE")
  private CustomDate date;

}
```

Comment: So if I am using datatype SET in mysql database which annotation to be used and what should be the data type in java side?

Comment: database table structure is not clear in your question. Please update it with the complete structure.